# C++ What does having & after a function return type declaration do?

Tags: c++

I'm learning about copy assignment operator overloading and one of the examples has this function

```
MyClass& MyClass::operator=(const MyClass& objToCopy) {
   cout << "Assignment op called." << endl;
   if (this != &objToCopy) {           // 1. Don't self-assign
      delete dataObj;                  // 2. Delete old dataObj
      dataObj = new int;               // 3. Allocate new dataObj
    *dataObj = *(objToCopy.dataObj); // 4. Copy dataObj

  }
 return *this;
}
```

What does the & after the MyClass do? Does it mean that the function will return a reference to this instead of a copy?

Comment: It's telling the compiler that you're returning a reference. A reference to your current class instance in your particular case.

Comment: It's not after the type, the type *is* `MyClass&`. If you're completely unfamiliar with references, I think you've approached operator overloading a bit early.